# How to use cppcheck-suppress command to elimnate the error about "a parameter should be passed by reference"

Tags: c++, cppcheck

In function "writeFile" below it has the following signature:

```
writeFile(std::string fileId, std::string otherVariable){}
```

when I run it, an error:  `Function parameter 'aFileId' should be passed by const reference. [passedByValue]` is recieved. However I don't want to pass it by const reference because the function is going to be binary incompatiable with other files. I wanted to do a "cppcheck suppress"
to make it igone this. I tried the following

```
// cppcheck-suppress aFileId
writeFile(std::string aFileId, std::string otherVariable){}
```

but it does not really work and I still get the same error.

To clarify more, I tried this as well...

```
writeFile(std::string aFileId,  // cppcheck-suppress aFileId
     std::string otherVariable) 
    {
       // stuff
    }
```

Comment: Put the comment on the same line (at the end).

Comment: I tried that too. It does not work.

Comment: Is the "suppres" typo present in your code as well?

Comment: No No, It is correctly spelt there

Comment: And the variable name is spelled correctly as well? Your message complains about `aFileId` but you suppress `aFiled`... Please use copy/paste to make sure we at least get the _actual_ code and error instead of accidentally introducing typos.

Comment: Sorry for that. But no, in the original code it is correctly spelt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to activate inline suppressions in general when calling cppcheck. Add the command line option `--inline-suppr`.

Comment: Oh hello Jan, yeah that works. Thanks for response